# Logging into a server and parsing files on that server with Python

Tags: python, http, session

I would like to be able to use a Python script that I wrote to search files to login to an Ubuntu server that's password protected (which I have credentials ), and search files on that server.. Is there a straight forward way to accomplish this?

Comment: Your question is too vague.  If you don't have a login ID and password you won't be able to do anything.  What do you mean by "parse"?  Do you want to write a script that logs in to a server via a telnet or ssh connection and then operates on files on the server?  Please clarify.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To login and run remote terminal commands through python, you should use either [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) or [pexpect](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/2.4).  `Pexpect` is not touched very much by noah these days... I'm starting to wonder whether he is abandoning it.

The other way is to `sftp` the files from the remote server to your local machine... `paramiko` is useful for that as well.